# Regex to match starts with

Tags: regex, postgresql

I need to update a table setting attribute MATCH to True where the attribute_a STARTS with the Value of attribute_b.

Somehow I can't get the correct syntax in Postgresql to do this pattern match.

```
UPDATE table   
   SET  match= True  
WHERE attribute_a ~ '^attribute_b' ;
```

eg MATCH TRUE: attribute_a = Nelson Mandela ; attribute_b = 'Nelson'

Comment: `'^attribute_b'` will match, if the value starts with literally `'attribute_b...'` -- `('^' || attribute_b)` however does what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need pattern matching, use [`left()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html), e.g.:

```
with my_table(attribute_a, attribute_b) as (
values 
    ('Nelson Mandela', 'Nelson'),
    ('Donald Trump', 'Donald Duck'),
    ('John Major', 'John M')
)

select *
from my_table
where attribute_b = left(attribute_a, length(attribute_b));

  attribute_a   | attribute_b 
----------------+-------------
 Nelson Mandela | Nelson
 John Major     | John M
(2 rows)
```

If you absolutely want to use regex, you have to build the pattern with `concat()` or `format()`, like this:

```
select *
from my_table
where attribute_a ~ concat('^', attribute_b)
-- where attribute_a ~ format('^%s', attribute_b)
```

Comment: Thanks Klin - also  WHERE attribute_a ~ ('^' || attribute_b); worked for me . I belleive this is a variation to the concat() method you just added.